# how to extract integer from a string and assign each set of strings to different variables?

Tags: c

I have the following string.

```
str[]="10,2";
```

I want to assign '10' to:

```
int n;
```

and '2' to:

```
int k;
```

I tried using index, string copy and many more methods, but didn't work.

Comment: Use `sscanf` for this job.

Comment: `str[]="10,2";` is not valid C. Show what you have so far and where you are stuck. We are not a coding service. Briefly: read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n,k;
    char str[]="10,2";
    if(sscanf(str,"%d,%d",&n,&k)==2)//it will return 2, if both parameter has been assigned
        printf("%d %d\n",n,k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... and check the return value

Comment: ok, i have edited.